# Very odd iOS /PHP - 'if' statement works over iOS but not on a browser

Tags: php, html, ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm very confused here. Basically, I have an iOS app that uploads a string to a .php file on my blue host server.

```
-(IBAction)plus{
if (counter>=0 && counter<240) {
counter=counter+1;
count.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",counter];

    NSString* myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",counter];

    NSString *receipt1 = @"This should work?";

    NSString *post =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"receipt=%@",receipt1];
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding 
allowLossyConversion:YES];

    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    [request setURL:[NSURL 
URLWithString:@"http://www.ryanmediaworks.com/validation.php"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-
Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    NSHTTPURLResponse* urlResponse = nil;
    NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request 
returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&error];
    NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData   
encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Response Code: %d", [urlResponse statusCode]);

    if ([urlResponse statusCode] >= 200 && [urlResponse statusCode] < 600)
    {
        NSLog(@"Response: %@", result);
    }

}

}
```

Here is my .php file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"  
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>I hope this works!</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php

if(_POST)
    {
 if($_POST['receipt'] == 'This should work?')
        {
            echo "post successfull";
        }
        else
    {
        echo "not post";
        }
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the weird part...This is what is on my browser:

```
<head>
    <title>I hope this works!</title>
</head>
<body>
    not post</body>
</html>
```

BUT here is the output in Xcode:

```
<head>
    <title>I hope this works!</title>
</head>
<body>
    post successfull</body>
</html>
```

It appears that the 'if' statement works over xcode but not on a browser? In other words, the correct string is uploaded to the .php, so the phrase 'post sucessfull' is returned. However, the phrase is not present when viewed in the browser?

I'd really appreciate any help on this!

Comment: In the first `if` in your PHP, did you mean `if($_POST)`?

Comment: Just tried that, the php doesn't work at all when I make that change. It also does not appear to work on Xcode either.

Comment: Post the HTML/Javascript that submits this from the browser. It's apparently not filling in the `receipt` field.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what yo're asking me to post? I've put up all of the code I have I think. The browser is accessing the .php file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems strange. Try this

```
if(isset($_POST['receipt'])
{
 if($_POST['receipt'] == 'This should work?')
    {
        echo "post successfull";
    }
    else
{
    echo "not post";
    }
}
?>
```

Also when you check your browser, is it after you do a post request from that same browser (e.g. through a form POST)?

Your iOS code is doing a post and that's why its returns successful. If you are just loading the .php file without doing any type of post to that .php page prior on that same device/browser it will show "not post".